# Different results on my laptop and on a cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I have a problem that makes me lose my mind.

I have an application that uses **Kmeans from mllib** and if I launch it on my **laptop** gives me a **result** and on a **cluster** from AWS gives me another completely **different**. In fact, I launched several times on my laptop and on AWS cluster and the results from each platforms are similar, but they should be similar in both platforms.

I am not using Repartition, I'm just executing it with default parameters.

Any solution?
Thanks

Comment: K-means is randomized. It is supposed to give different results.

Comment: Yes, it is. But, as I said, I launched several times on my laptop and on AWS cluster and the results from each platforms are similar, but they should be similar in both platforms.

Comment: Maybe a bug? Spark clustering is crap.

Answer (score 0):

Spark Kmeans will randomize the initial centroids. Try setting the random seed to a fix value.

```
val kmeansModel = new Kmeans().setSeed(1L).setK(k)
```